# Jquery if/elseif not hiding after going back and forth

Tags: jquery

Decided to start learning jquery to enhance my html+css.
I've been stuffing around with the statements below, I'm trying to hide/show input fields based on the selection a person puts on a radio button (Radio buttons are called oneFacesLabel, twoFacesLabel and threeFacesLabel).

Works at the start, but once all 3 are shown if I click on the first option it doesn't hide the other 2. I can see why it doesn't trigger, I tried to put else after every if to hide the options but can't else if after. What options do I have?

EDIT: to explain more, if user picks oneFaceLabel then image1 shows, if they pick twofacelabel, then image1 and image2 show, if they go back to onefacelabel then image2 should disappear

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
            if ($(this).attr('id') == 'oneFaceLabel') {
                $('#image1').show();
            } else if ($(this).attr('id') == 'twoFacesLabel') {
                $('#image1').show();
                $('#image2').show();
            } else if ($(this).attr('id') == 'threeFacesLabel') {
                $('#image1').show();
                $('#image2').show();
                $('#image3').show();
            } else {
                $('#image1').hide();
                $('#image2').hide();
                $('#image3').hide();
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Hi , you can just hide all image first i.e :`$('.someimageclass').hide();` put this before `if` statement and see onces.

Comment: @Swati hey, the images are already hidden at the start. what im trying to accomplish if user picks oneFaceLabel then image1 shows, if they pick twofacelabel, then image1 and image2 show, if they go back to onefacelabel then image2 should disappear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, I hide all images before showing selected images based on the radio button selected.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
    $('.img').hide(); // Hide all images here
    if ($(this).attr('id') === 'oneFaceLabel') {
      $('#image1').show();
    } else if ($(this).attr('id') === 'twoFacesLabel') {
      $('#image1').show();
      $('#image2').show();
    } else if ($(this).attr('id') === 'threeFacesLabel') {
      $('#image1').show();
      $('#image2').show();
      $('#image3').show();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
img {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<input type='radio' name='name' id='oneFaceLabel' />1
<br />
<input type='radio' name='name' id='twoFacesLabel' />2
<br />
<input type='radio' name='name' id='threeFacesLabel' />3
<br />
<div style='display: flex'>
<img id='image1' class='img' src='http://placehold.it/100x100'>
&nbsp;
<img id='image2' class='img' src='http://placehold.it/100x100'>
&nbsp;
<img id='image3' class='img' src='http://placehold.it/100x100'>
</div>
```

Comment: DERP i found my mistake I was targetting the label rather than the img itself, thanks for the help, I found the mistake while comparing your code to mine

Answer (score 0):

- Add Class rdBtn to all radio button, we will use this to capture the click event for the radio buttons
- Add value="1", value="2" for you radio buttons, this will be used to determine which value type radio button is clicked

  img{
               display:none;           
           }

  ```
       <input type='radio' name='name' id='oneFaceLabel' class="rdBtn" value="1" />1
       <br />
       <input type='radio' name='name' id='twoFacesLabel' class="rdBtn" value="2" />2
       <br />
       <input type='radio' name='name' id='threeFacesLabel' class="rdBtn" value="3" />3
       <br />
       <div style='display: flex'>
           <img id='image1' class='img' src='http://placehold.it/100x100'>
           &nbsp;
           <img id='image2' class='img' src='http://placehold.it/100x100'>
           &nbsp;
           <img id='image3' class='img' src='http://placehold.it/100x100'>
       </div>
   <script type="text/javascript">
       $(".rdBtn").click(function(){
           /*Lets Hide all the images by class DOm selector*/
           $(".img").hide();

           /*Lets save what value radio button we have pressed*/
           var i = parseInt($(this).val());

           /*now lets start your loop from 1*/
           for(x=1;x<=i;x++)
           {
               $("#image"+x).show();
           }

       })
   </script>
  ```

> The idea is
>
> - Hide all images
> - Get the value of radio button clicked
> - Loop for all images until the value, say for example you click number 2, then all images will be hide and loop will run from 1 - 2
>   showing image1 and image2
>
> Really appreciate you learning jQuery, Best of luck